# Lifetime cycle config is longer than 5 minutes, nohup command not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, yum

I am trying to install a number of dependencies for my jupyter notebook, but would like them to be permanent to save me 20 minutes every time I restart the notebook. I have opted for using a lifecycle configuration, however, my script takes longer than 5 minutes to run. I found this article (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sagemaker-lifecycle-script-timeout/) to help resolve this problem, however, my notebook is still failing to start with the following error:

```
Notebook Instance Lifecycle Config 'arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-west-2:347285168835:notebook-instance-lifecycle-config/nbs-aap-dev-dsar' for Notebook Instance 'arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-west-2:347285168835:notebook-instance/nbs-aap-dev-dsar' took longer than 5 minutes. Please check your CloudWatch logs for more details if your Notebook Instance has Internet access.
```

Here is the script I am trying to run:

```
sudo nohup yum install wget &
sudo yum install autoconf &
sudo yum install automake &
sudo yum install libtool &
sudo yum install jpeg &
sudo yum install tiff &
sudo yum install libpng &
sudo yum install tiff2png &
sudo yum install libtiff &
sudo yum install autoconf aclocal automake &
sudo yum install libtool &
sudo yum -y install libjpeg-devel libpng-devel libpng-devel libtiff-devel zlib-devel &
sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++ make &
sudo wget https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica/releases/download/1.82.0/leptonica-1.82.0.tar.gz &
sudo tar xzvf leptonica-1.82.0.tar.gz &
cd leptonica-1.82.0 &
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ &
sudo make &
sudo make install &
sudo wget https://codeload.github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/tar.gz/4.1.1 &
sudo tar -zxvf 4.1.1 &
cd tesseract-4.1.1 &
sudo ./autogen.sh &
sudo cp /home/ec2-user/leptonica-1.82.0/lept.pc /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/. &
sudo LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=/usr/local/lib ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ --with-extra-libraries=/usr/local/lib &
sudo make &
sudo make install &
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib &
sudo ldconfig &
sudo wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best/raw/main/eng.traineddata &
sudo mv -v eng.traineddata /usr/local/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata &
sudo wget https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs9550/ghostpdl-9.55.0.tar.gz &
sudo tar -zxvf ghostpdl-9.55.0.tar.gz &
cd ghostpdl-9.55.0 &
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ &
sudo make &
sudo make install &
sudo yum -y install poppler-utils &
sudo wget https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/releases/download/release-qpdf-10.1.0/qpdf-10.1.0.tar.gz &
sudo tar xzvf qpdf-10.1.0.tar.gz &
cd qpdf-10.1.0 &
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ &
sudo make &
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add ampersand `&` on the end of the lines. This put them in background and execute some commands in parallel which lead to odd conditions. For example in code:

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ &
sudo make &
sudo make install &
```

the command `make` start before end of `configure` and will not end well in most of the cases. Same for `make install` it try to install the compiled package before it is compiled from `make`
If you want to put script in background you can group the commands on this way:

```
sudo nohup yum -y install wget autoconf automake libtool jpeg tiff libpng tiff2png libtiff autoconf aclocal automake libtool libjpeg-devel libpng-devel libpng-devel libtiff-devel zlib-devel gcc gcc-c++ make poppler-utils 

nohup sudo wget https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica/releases/download/1.82.0/leptonica-1.82.0.tar.gz && sudo tar xzvf leptonica-1.82.0.tar.gz &&cd leptonica-1.82.0 && sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ && sudo make && sudo make install &

nohup sudo wget https://codeload.github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/tar.gz/4.1.1 &&sudo tar -zxvf 4.1.1 && cd tesseract-4.1.1 && sudo ./autogen.sh && sudo cp /home/ec2-user/leptonica-1.82.0/lept.pc /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/. && sudo LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=/usr/local/lib ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ --with-extra-libraries=/usr/local/lib && sudo make && sudo make install &

nohup export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib && sudo ldconfig && sudo wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best/raw/main/eng.traineddata && sudo mv -v eng.traineddata /usr/local/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata && sudo wget https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs9550/ghostpdl-9.55.0.tar.gz && sudo tar -zxvf ghostpdl-9.55.0.tar.gz && cd ghostpdl-9.55.0 && sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ && sudo make && sudo make install &

nohup sudo wget https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/releases/download/release-qpdf-10.1.0/qpdf-10.1.0.tar.gz && sudo tar xzvf qpdf-10.1.0.tar.gz && cd qpdf-10.1.0 && sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ && sudo make && sudo make install &
```

Comment: So I have changed it to: `sudo su
nohup yum install wget
nohup yum install autoconf
nohup yum install automake
nohup yum install libtool
nohup yum install jpeg
nohup yum install tiff
nohup yum install libpng
nohup yum install tiff2png
nohup yum install libtiff ` etc.. but it still does not seem to be working.

Comment: I need the commands to be in the background as there is a 5 minute limit on the script I can run on a lifetime configuration.

Comment: you do not need also `nohup` as this utility work de-attach from terminal. Better add all packages to be installed on one line: `sudo yum install wget autoconf automake libtool jpeg tiff libpng tiff2png libtiff autoconf aclocal automake libtool `

Comment: This will pass the 5 minute time limit though

Comment: i'm using nohup so that it will continue running in the background even if the time limit fails

Comment: @Kelly, see my edited answer

Comment: That seems to be working! Thank you, how do I check if the process is finished or not in my sagemaker terminal?

Comment: @Kelly, this is another question, please create new: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: I am still getting a few errors running this code: 

`mv: cannot move 'eng.traineddata' to '/usr/local/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata': No such file or directory` 
     
`cp: cannot stat '/home/ec2-user/leptonica-1.82.0/lept.pc': No such file or directory` 
     
`flag during linking and do at least one of the following:  
- add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable  during execution  
- add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable  during linking  
- use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag  
- have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'`

Comment: mv: cannot move 'eng.traineddata' to '/usr/local/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata': No such file or directory

Comment: cp: cannot stat '/home/ec2-user/leptonica-1.82.0/lept.pc': No such file or directory

Comment: Not sure how to correct this because none of them show up in my home directory on the sagmaker terminal

Comment: @Kelly, in such case will be better to open new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask